How can one disable the content filter in Azure OpenAI?
How can one disable the content filter in Azure OpenAI? I only see "default" as the option:

but "default" option  does content filtering:


Update 2024-11-25: Azure changed their web UI, creating a new content filter is done here:

And conveniently, one may apply a new content filter to several instances at once:


One may modify the content filter in Azure OpenAI upon approval.  From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/cognitive-services/openai/limited-access:

Customers who wish to modify content filters and modify abuse monitoring after they have onboarded to the service are subject to additional eligibility criteria and scenario restrictions. At this time, modified content filters and/or modified abuse monitoring for Azure OpenAI Service are only available to managed customers and partners working with Microsoft account teams and have additional use case restrictions. Customers meeting these requirements can register for:

Modified content filters

Modified abuse monitoring


Access to the Azure OpenAI Service is subject to Microsoft's sole discretion based on eligibility criteria and a vetting process, and customers must acknowledge that they have read and understand the Azure terms of service for Azure OpenAI Service.

It is supposed to take ~10 business days:


In my case the application was approved in 15 hours. See here to learn how to how to set up a customized content filtering configuration for a resource, or see these screenshots:






To test in python:
import os
from openai import AzureOpenAI

parameters = {}
parameters['azure'] = {}
parameters['azure']['api_version'] = '2023-07-01-preview'

####### GPT-4o instance
parameters['azure']['api_key'] = '156dfg651df651gfdg'
parameters['azure']['azure_endpoint'] = 'https://example-instance.openai.azure.com/'
parameters['azure']['model'] = 'my-gpt-4o-model'

client = AzureOpenAI(
        api_key=parameters['azure']['api_key'],
        azure_endpoint = parameters['azure']['azure_endpoint'],
        api_version = parameters['azure']['api_version'],
    )

llm_system_prompt = 'hey'
llm_user_prompt = 'I need to get rid of white magins of a pdf doc, and I am unable to figure out how. Is this possible to do it in Acrobat'
messages = [{"role": "system", "content": llm_system_prompt},
            {"role": "user", "content": llm_user_prompt}]


chat_completion = client.chat.completions.create(messages=messages, model=parameters['azure']['model'],
                                                 temperature=0, seed=47)
print(chat_completion)
print('\n\n\nanswer', chat_completion.choices[0].message.content)

answer = chat_completion.choices[0].message.content


